# Magento 2: How many tables required to change Order Status Programmatically?

Tags: magento2, orders, custom, order-status, query

Would like to change order status throgh Magento 2 MySQL Query

But Order Status belongs to so many tables like

```
sales_order
sales_order_grid
```

Need to use `sales_order_aggregated_created` & `sales_order_aggregated_updated`?

In `sales_order_status_state` what's difference between Status & State?

**Example: Status is fraud, but Stat is payment_review.**

Can use below method to update order status

```
$update = $collection->update('sales_order', [
                    'status' => 'complete',
                ], ["entiry_id = ?" => 1]
        );
```

In how many tables I have to change status? Will don't have like update in 1 table & changes will be applied in respective relational tables.

How to update multiple tables at same time

Example

```
$update = $collection->update('sales_order','sales_order_grid'
```

Comment: Sorry @krishnaijjadaati95Dev updated question. How many & how to do at one time, as i have given example. Not sure possible

Answer (score 3):

**What's difference between Order Status & Order State?**

They both are different.

**State** is used by magento to tell if the order is new, processing, complete, holded, closed, canceled, etc.

**Status** are the one that you would be defining at the backend in **Store -> Settings -> Order Status**.

**Magento displays order STATUSES and not STATES** in the backend order detail page to let you know which status is assigned as per your mapping.

Remember, multiple statuses can be mapped with one state, while vice versa is not possible.

For more info check [link](http://ka.lpe.sh/2012/04/21/magento-order-state-vs-status/)

Below two table is responsible for order status

```
sales_order_grid
sales_order
```

For more info please check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338457/change-order-status-in-magento-via-sql)

Comment: Hi @Prasshant u can just put link in comment below question regarding this. Actual question is different.

Comment: @PrashantValanda Magento 2 Don't have tables `sales_flat_order` & `sales_flat_order_grid`. Please double check

Comment: @AnkitShah update answer please check it

Comment: @PrashantValanda 60% Achieved. 2 Thinks still remain 1] Need to use sales_order_aggregated_created & sales_order_aggregated_updated? 2] How to update multiple table at same time

Comment: @PrashantValanda If required then also can Post Separate Question for above 2 remaining points as 1 question contains multiple questions. Up to you