# Magento 2: Update Multiple Tables At Once

Tags: magento2, database, collection, sales-order, order-status

In Continue with

[Magento 2: How many tables required to change Order Status Programmatically?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139208/magento-2-how-many-tables-required-to-change-order-status-programmatically/)

I have below code

```
$orderIds = array();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orderCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection');
$update = $orderCollection->update('sales_order_grid', ['status' => 'complete',], ["entity_id", ["in" => $orderIds]]);

$orderCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection');
$update = $orderCollection->update('sales_order', ['status' => 'complete',], ["entity_id", ["in" => $orderIds]]);
```

Can i update at both tables at 1 time or one go like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765490/mysql-update-two-tables-at-once

Looking for answer in Magento 2 Way, if above is possible

Comment: If you do update in transaction there no differents to update one or two table

Comment: @KAndy Question still remains how to update multiple tables at one shot? Above is just example. I'm talking about in General for Magento 2